# A question about large cardinal axioms in set theory

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics

In set theory, there are many kinds of large cardinal axioms. Their existence cannot be proved in [Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory). But for many large cardinal properties, if we don't need them be uncountable infinitely, "they are "reflect" to smaller cardinals" [unclear what this means].
For example, 0 and omega are inaccessible, because they are regular and strong limit cardinal[s?]. Omega is even weakly compact, measurable... if we believe smaller cardinals, such as 0 and omega, to actually exist, does it means the "large cardinal property" may happen again on very big cardinals, as the cardinals go on forever? Should we *believe* large cardinal axioms to be true, though we cannot prove it to be exist, by Godel's incompleteness?

Comment: How on earth is this connected to metaphysics?  :)

Comment: It's related to existence (and of abstract objects, no less), which makes the question an ontological one (and thus metaphysical).

Comment: In answer to the OP, you might want to look at a couple of papers by Penelope Maddy called 'Believing the axioms I & II', which discuss in detail just this question -- when to believe large cardinal axioms.

Comment: @J.P. -They have been expanded in book lenght into Penelope Maddy, [Defending the Axioms: On the Philosophical Foundations of Set Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Defending-Axioms-Philosophical-Foundations-Theory/dp/0199596182)

Comment: Godel's Incompleteness Th has nothing to do with set-theory *large cardinal axioms* ... Every theory "postulates" with its axioms the existence of something : in *arithmetic* we have postulates stating that each number has a successor. In ZFC we have postulates stating the existence of the emptyset and the power-set (for each set). With this postulates we can prove something... and something other not.

Comment: You should clean this up (or someone with a math background help clean up his English) so it's more readable. I did what I could. From what I understood, this appears to be more of a math question.

Answer (score 1):

large cardinals can't be proved - they're additional axioms of infinity, the usual infinity axiom in ZF can be regarded as the smallest infinity axiom. The reason why mathematicians investigate them is because they reveal a rich structure amongst other things. They also come up when asking natural questions - in the mathematicians sense - about model theory. This is reminiscent of how imaginary, irrational or infinitesimal numbers were discovered.

Godels incompleteness theorem here is something of a red herring. What can one one prove if I give you nothing to start out with?

Mathematicians do not use proof in a simple-minded way, the Philosopher of science, Whitehead put it well - that its the general structure and coherence that is revealed that affirms that the axioms model something that one wishes to explore.